# Alamofire 4.0 "extra argument 'method' in call" when wrapped in static function

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am writing a method to contain an Alamofire network request in Swift 3/Xcode 8. When wrapped in a standard function the following block of code compiles without error:

```
func registerUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, username: String, password: String, profilePicture: String, completion: @escaping(JSON?) -> ()) {
    let params: [String:Any]? = [
        "first_name" : firstName,
        "last_name" : lastName,
        "email" : email,
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password,
        "profile_pic" : profilePicture
    ]

    Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)/users/create", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        switch response .result {
        case .success(let value) :
            completion(JSON(value))
        case .failure(let error) :
            let error = error as Error
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I make this function static I receive the error "extra argument 'method' in call". I have attempted the solutions listed in posts with similar questions with no positive results. Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Comment: try to remove header if it is nil or if not nil then it should be [String: String]

Comment: It probably means there's a similar static function in the same scope. Can you post the other bits of code in the same scope with the containing class/struct?

Comment: Removing headers leads to the same result. There is not a similar static method in the same scope. This is the only method currently contained in this class.

Comment: Where is `baseURL` defined?

Comment: Issue solved. Looks like it was a scoping issue involving baseURL being outside of the method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction dan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue resolved for the time being. It was a scoping issue with the `baseURL` variable not being inside the method. The following will build for me.

```
func registerUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, username: String, password: String, profilePicture: String, completion: @escaping(JSON?) -> ()) {
    let baseURL = "url"
    let params: [String:Any]? = [
        "first_name" : firstName,
        "last_name" : lastName,
        "email" : email,
        "username" : username,
        "password" : password,
        "profile_pic" : profilePicture
    ]

    Alamofire.request("\(baseURL)/users/create", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        switch response .result {
        case .success(let value) :
            completion(JSON(value))
        case .failure(let error) :
            let error = error as Error
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```